# Coldfusion how to repeat the same task of another case

Tags: coldfusion, switch-statement

I have a switch statement like this:

```html
<cfswitch expression="#action#">
  <cfcase value="caseone">
    // do task one
  </cfcase>
  <cfcase value="casetwo">
    // repeat task one
    // Also do another task here
  </cfcase>
</cfswitch>
```

Is there an easy way that I can repeat the same task of caseone in casetwo?(instead of copying the long piece of code from caseone)

Comment: put task one's code in a function and call it. That way the code is only in one place, but called from both case statements. You could do it by catching caseone or casetwo in your case statement then conditionally running casetwo, but a function would be much better.

Comment: If the value is casetwo, you would not be repeating task one, you would be performing it for the first time.

Answer (score 7):

You could do like this:

create a function, perform task one there and call that function from two cfswitch cases like below:

```
<cffunction name="taskOne">
    do task one
</cffunction>

<cfswitch expression="#action#">
    <cfcase value="caseone">
       <cfset taskOne() >
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="casetwo">
       <cfset taskOne() >
       // Also do another task here
    </cfcase>
</cfswitch>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cfscript and one or more functions if the actions need to use cfml:

```
<cfscript>
    switch(yourExpression) {
        case "a": case "b": case "c":
            …something…
            break;
        case "d":
            …something else…
            break;
        default:
            … default behaviour goes here …
            break;
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I have used cases in one line as you did in this code example `case "a": case "b": case "c":` but i am getting error.

Is this way of defining case depreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Using function is a good solution. Another work around is, **if your code contains only two cases means**, you can use the code as follows

```
// do task for caseone as well as for casetwo
<cfif action EQ "casetwo">
 // do task two alone
</cfif>
```

And if you need to **repeat the code** in casetwo means

```
<cffunction name="task">
   // do task for caseone as well as for casetwo
</cffunction>

<cfset task()>
<cfif action EQ "casetwo">
    <cfset task()>
 // do task two alone
</cfif>
```